# "Bot was not started" error while integrating Twitter with dialogflow bot

Tags: twitter, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to integrate chatbot (built using Dialogflow) with twitter. I have read the documentation and followed all the steps correctly from Dialogflow's tab. Below given are the keys that I got from Twitter's Developer Console and this keys we have to enter in the Dialogflow's Console

```
Bot Username :
Consumer Key : 
Consumer Secret Key :
Access Token :
Access Token secret :
```

When I press `Start bot` after filling the information on the Dialogflow console the only error message displayed is `Bot was not started` that's it. I referred [This](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dialogflow/YaK4f-uZAUA/dcs9oMFODwAJ) Url but didn't found something that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the "Dev environments" at https://developer.twitter.com/en/account/environments

Comment: You should add the relevant link content to your response with the link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a long time - it was a problem under the hood and wasn't fixable by an end user. I realised this by creating a brand new agent and trying Twitter integration with that - it worked first time!

So I exported my old bot as a zip file (*Settings* -> *Export and Import* -> *Export as Zip*), then created a brand new Dialogflow agent and loaded the zip file into it (*Settings* -> *Export and Import* -> *Restore from Zip*).

The new agent integrated with Twitter without any issues. The only pain was that I had other existing integrations which then needed to be migrated to the new agent.